# If the user input is a string how do you tell the user to input a number

Tags: python, string

```
 user_input = float(input("Please enter a multiplier!")
 if user_input == int:
     print " Please enter a number"
 else:
    for multiplier in range (1,13,1):
        print multiplier, "x", user_input, " = ", multiplier * user_input
```

The program  will run effectively, as for any number entered by the user the result will be effective, yet I wish to know a function that allows the user to ask for a number when they enter a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that's a `float` is not an `int`. They're separate types. You can have a `float` that represents an integral value, like `1.0`, but it's still a `float`.

(Also, `user_input == int` isn't checking whether `user_input` is an `int`, it's checking whether `user_input` is actually the *type* `int`; you wanted `isinstance(user_input, int)`. But since that still won't work, let's skim over this part…)

---

So, can you check that a `float` has an integral value? Well, you can do this:

```
if int(user_input) == user_input
```

Why? Because `1.0` and `1` are equal, even though they're not the same type, while `1.1` and `1` are not equal. So, truncating a `float` to an `int` changes the value into something not-equal if it's not an integral value.

But there's a problem with this. `float` is inherently a lossy type. For example, `10000000000000000.1` *is* equal to `10000000000000000` (on any platform with IEEE-854 double as the `float` type, which is almost all platforms), because a `float` can't handle enough precision to distinguish between the two. So, assuming you want to disallow the first one, you have to do it *before* you convert to `float`.

---

How can you do that? The easiest way to check whether something is possible in Python is to `try` it. You can get the user input as a string by calling `raw_input` instead of `input`, and you can try to convert it to an `int` with the `int` function. so:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter a multiplier!")
try:
    user_input = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print " Please enter a number"
```

---

If you need to ultimately convert the input to a `float`, you can always do that after converting it to an `int`:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter a multiplier!")
try:
    user_input = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print " Please enter a number"
else:
    user_input = float(user_input)
```

Comment: what if i mean instead an int a str @abarnert because i wish if th e user enters a letter to enter a number instead(wishing a float) and also do you know why in the codeskulptor software says 'Line 1: undefined: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://www.codeskulptor.org/skulpt/skulpt.min.js :: Sk.inputfun :: line 54"  data: no]' to the depicted code you created previouusly?

Comment: If you want a `str`, then `raw_input` is all you need; no checking, no converting, you're guaranteed to get a `str`. Meanwhile, I have no idea how to debug problems in a not-quite-Python interpreter on an example I can't see. If you have a new problem, ask a new question, so you can provide complete details. (I think CodeSkulptor has a way to create a "permalink" to an example, doesn't it? Most such sites do… And of course you can put your complete code in the question, too, which is impossible in a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `try/except` inside a `while` loop:

```
 while True:
    try:
        user_input = float(raw_input("Please enter a multiplier!"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input, please enter a number"
        continue # if we get here input is invalid so ask again
    else: # else user entered  correct input
        for multiplier in range (1,13,1):
            print multiplier, "x", user_input, " = ", multiplier * user_input
        break
```

Comment: With this approach you can use `raw_input()` and avoid the security issues associated with `input()` (assuming Python 2.x).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yep, forgot to change input.

Comment: it says "Component is not available" in line 3 though in both codeskultor and repl.it python language online softwareswhat does that mean?

Comment: have you tried running it in an interpreter?

Comment: @DeborahIsrael, it means that repl.it and codeskultor aren't sufficiently close to the behavior of a genuine out-of-the-box Python interpreter.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the assert-statment in python:

```
assert type(user_input) == int, 'Not a number'
```

This should raise an AssertionError if type is not int. The function controlling your interface could than handle the AssertionError e.g. by restarting the dialog-function

Comment: This relies on `input()` -- not a good practice in Python 2.x, since it `eval()`s content and so can run arbitrary code.

Comment: Given that `user_input` is guaranteed to be a `float`, this will just always assert, which isn't very useful. Also, `assert` is meant to catch logic errors in the code, like "Shouldn't be able to get here no matter what input we got", not for user errors.

Comment: You are right, I missed to part, that she uses float() to directly convert the user input, than my solution would not work. On the usage of assert we seem to disagree a bit.